# How can I show codeigniter form validation messages in an alertbox

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am trying to adapt Ion auth to work with ajax, because my login form is a fixed size, i want to alert the error messages when a form is submitted with incorrect data.

The messages are returned from the controller like this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
```

and picked up in the view like this:

```
<div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message;?></div>
```

I am trying to display them as follows:

```
<?php   if((isset($message))&&($message!='')){
            echo '<script> alert("'.$message.'"); </script>';
        }
?>
```

This isn't working, the alert is not being displayed, I have removed the message delimiters but this didn't help. My only thought is it must be something to do with the way codeigniter is creating a new line in the middle of my javascript as it is coming out like this:

```
<script>
alert('The Identity field is required.
The Password field is required.');
</script>
```

How can I get rid of this newline and replace it in a way that wont break my js?

Comment: You are using jQuery or vanilla Javascript?

Comment: both are at my disposal, so a jquery solution would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php   
    if((isset($message))&&($message!='')){
        echo '<script> alert("'.str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '', $message).'"); </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you - The alert is now working but it is now not creating a new line between messages, any ideas?

Comment: You can try replacing the `str_replace` replacement part to '\n', like this: `echo '<script> alert("'.str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '\n', $message).'"); </script>';`, note though, there should be single quotes in the replacement part, as we want `\n` to be parsed as new line by JS, but as text by PHP!

Answer (score 0):

In `config/routes.php` add string:

```
$route["action"] = "mycontroller/validation";
```

where `mycontroller` is the classname of your controller, where you process ajax queries, and `validation` is the name of method of this controller.

When you pass data through jQuery method `.ajax()` or it alias `.post()`, you can use results of server response as it described in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.post( "validation",
{
    username: $( '#username' ).val(),
    password: $( '#password' ).val()
},
function( data )
{
    alert( 'message: ' + data );
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "validation",
    username: $( '#username' ).val(),
    password: $( '#password' ).val()
}).done( function( data )
{
    alert( 'message: ' + data );
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'validation',
    data: { username: $( '#username' ).val(), password: $( '#password' ).val() }
    success: function( data ) 
    {
        alert( 'message: ' + data );
    }
});
```